# Why does this call work to Postman from Curl but not Python

Tags: python, curl, postman

Curl Code works python does not

trying to change from curl to python

```
curl --location --request PUT "https://api.getpostman.com/environments/XXXXX-YYYYYY-ZZZZ-BBBB-AAAA-ZZZZZZ?apikey=12334567890" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data "{
    \"environment\": {
        \"values\": [
            {\"key\": \"url\", \"value\": \"http://10.12.30.131\"}
        ]
    }
}"



import requests
import json
url = 'https://api.getpostman.com/environments/XXXXX-YYYYYY-ZZZZ-BBBB-AAAA-ZZZZZZ?apikey=12334567890'
header = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
body = '{\"environment\": { \"name\": \"Prod - Deploy\", \"values\": [ {\"key\": \"url\", \"value\": \"http://10.12.30.131\"}]}}'
response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=header)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

expect a 200 response

Comment: Why are you escaping the double quotes in `body`?  Single-quoted strings can contain plain double quotes.  `message = '"Hello", he said.'`

Answer (score 0):

the body should be body = '{"environment\": {"name\": "Prod - Deploy\", "values\": [{"key\": "url\", "value\": "http://10.12.30.131\"}, {"key\": "appPath\", "value\": "footytips-apis-v1\"} ]}}'